"Synchronous Abort" error when running baremetal code in U-Boot on SK-TDA4VM (Cortex-R5)
I’m trying to run a simple baremetal code on U-Boot on my SK-TDA4VM board (Texas Instruments), which has ARM Cortex-A72 and Cortex-R5 processors. The code works fine when executed via Code Composer Studio, but when I try to run it directly on U-Boot, I encounter the "Synchronous Abort" error.
The code I’m trying to run is very simple and writes the value 12345678 to a random DDR memory address. Here are the details of my code:
Linker Script
ENTRY(_start)

MEMORY
{
    RAM (wrx) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 0x200 
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text : ALIGN(128) {       
        *(.text*)            
    } > RAM              
}

Assembly Code:
section .text
.global _start

_start:
    LDR R0, =0x81000000  
    LDR R1, =0x12345678    
    STR R1, [R0]         
loop:
    B loop

The error returned is always:
"Synchronous Abort" handler, esr 0x02000000
Some context:

The SK-TDA4VM board has two Cortex-A72 cores and four Cortex-R5 cores.

I’m trying to run the code on one of the Cortex-R5 cores.

The code works directly in Code Composer Studio (a TI software that is capable of running code directly from my PC, where I can also debug the program), but not when I try to run it in U-Boot.

DDR memory is correctly configured for the address 0x80000000, as specified in my linker script.

I compiled the code using arm-none-eabi-gcc.

I tested the code in both ELF and BIN formats.

I tried running the code using the bootelf command (for ELF) and the go command (for BIN).


Here are more details of the error that appears in the U-Boot console when i try to run the code using "go":
=> go 0x80000000                                                                
## Starting application at 0x80000000 ...                                       
"Synchronous Abort" handler, esr 0x02000000                                     
elr: 000000000093e000 lr : 0000000080811d60 (reloc)                             
elr: 0000000080000000 lr : 00000000ffed3d60                                     
x0 : 0000000000000001 x1 : 00000000fdead308                                     
x2 : 00000000fdead308 x3 : 0000000080000000                                     
x4 : 0000000002800000 x5 : 00000000fde7f975                                     
x6 : 0000000000000030 x7 : 00000000fde7fe00                                     
x8 : 0000000000000010 x9 : 00000000ffffffd0                                     
x10: 000000000000000d x11: 0000000000000006                                     
x12: 00000000fde7ffa8 x13: 00000000fde80100                                     
x14: 0000000000000008 x15: 00000000fde7f975                                     
x16: 0000000080000000 x17: 0000000000000000                                     
x18: 00000000fdea1da0 x19: 00000000fdead308                                     
x20: 0000000080000000 x21: 0000000000000002                                     
x22: 00000000fdead300 x23: 0000000000000002                                     
x24: 00000000fffd8834 x25: 0000000000000000                                     
x26: 0000000000000000 x27: 0000000000000000                                     
x28: 00000000fdead360 x29: 00000000fde7fe00                                     
                                                                                
Code: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (464c457f)                            
Resetting CPU ... 

After this error, the board resets.
Additionally, I tried using mkimage to create an image file, as follows:
mkimage -A arm -T kernel -C none -O linux -a 0x80000000 -e 0x80000000 -n "test" -d test.bin test.img
However, when I try to boot the image with U-Boot using the bootm command, I get the error:
Wrong Image Type for bootm command 
ERROR -91: can't get kernel image! 


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

U-Boot runs on the A72 code. Bootelf will execute the code there.

@Xypron I had actually already tried running the code on the A72 core, using the ARMv8 compiler since I noticed those "X" registers specific to ARMv8 in the error message. However, the "Synchronous Abort" error still occurred. Do you think this issue could still be related to running on the wrong core, or could it be caused by something else?
